# Rubymine Thin with SSL options

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, thin, rubymine

I can use THIN with

```
bundle exec thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
```

It works in the console/terminal, perfectly

But when I try to append these options in rubymine under "Run/Debug Configurations" -> "Edit Script Arguments" I get:

```
/Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)  /Users/jan/RubymineProjects/myapp/script/rails server thin -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
/Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': invalid option: --ssl-verify (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `parse_options'
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:180:in `options'
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:54:in `set_environment'
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `new'
from /Users/jan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jan/RubymineProjects/myapp/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /Users/jan/RubymineProjects/myapp/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Process finished with exit code 1 
Can anyone help us / me out?

many thanks!

Comment: Cannot the ssl key and certificate file be specified in thin's configuration file (YAML)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got help here:

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5490676

It seems Rubymine can't parse such arguments, but a workaround is to do this with a Ruby script from Run/Debug Configurations

Answer (score 4):

Use following way

```
require 'rack'

SERVER_KEY = File.expand_path('../../ssl-cert/host.key',  __FILE__)
SERVER_PEM = File.expand_path('../../ssl-cert/host.crt',  __FILE__)

# Thin SSL workaround
module Rack
  module Handler
    class Thin
      def self.run(app, options={})
        app = Rack::Chunked.new(Rack::ContentLength.new(app))
        server = ::Thin::Server.new(options[:Host] || '0.0.0.0',
                                    options[:Port] || 3000,
                                    app)
        server.ssl = true
        server.ssl_options = {
            :private_key_file => SERVER_KEY,
            :cert_chain_file => SERVER_PEM
        }
        yield server if block_given?
        server.start
      end
    end
  end
end
# Workaround end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: From [this Github comment](https://gist.github.com/masone/5955f4cc0b4d4ef372db#gistcomment-1448440), if you want Thin to use its built-in self signed certificate, you can pass `nil` to `:private_key_file` and `:cert_chain_file`.

Answer (score 1):

The option `--ssl-verify` should not be used

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can actually be pulled off by adding a Procfile and the gem foreman, as in this set of instructions:

[Using Rails, Thin and SSL in RubyMine: The solution!](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206066479-Using-Rails-Thin-and-SSL-in-RubyMine-The-solution-)

Basically, you add foreman to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'foreman'
```

Then create a `Procfile` (*the link misspells this*) in your root containing this:

```
web: thin start --ssl
```

or, to bind to 0.0.0.0 as RubyMine usually does:

```
web: thin start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3001 --ssl
```

I did not need to specify the location of my ssl files, but if you wanted to it would be:

```
web: thin start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3001 --ssl --ssl-key-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
```

I would not recommend using `--ssl-verify` because that did not work for me.

Last, in RubyMine, create a new Ruby Configuration with the following attributes:

- **Ruby script**: This should be the path to the foreman executable, e.g.: `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset/gems/foreman-0.82.0/bin/foreman`
- **Script arguments**: `start`
- **Working directory**: The root directory of your project, e.g. `~/Sites/appname`

In the Bundler tab, check the only checkbox to use `bundle exec` when running it.

Last, in the logs tab, add a new log file pointing to `~/Sites/appname/logs/development.log`